# Remove unwanted rows from Query response

Tags: google-sheets

I have this query where I pull data from another sheet.

```
=QUERY(Dump!A:F, "SELECT A,F, COUNT(C) GROUP BY A,F label count(C) ''")
```

The response I get is this one:

[image: Response]

I´d like to NOT have the 0 row and the headers row. How can I do this?

Comment: =QUERY(Dump!A2:F,"SELECT A,F, COUNT(C) where A<>'' GROUP BY A,F label count(C) ''")

Comment: this works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MattKing, I highly suggest that you post your response as an answer :)

Comment: @RonM I kinda feel like this doesn't rise to the level of a question for stack, since the answer is answered many places for sure? I just didn't want to downvote it. But wanted the OP to have the answer they needed.

Comment: Include an explicit `headers` parameter to avoid surprises: `=query(Dump!A1:F, "select A, F, count(C) group by A, F label count(C) '' ", 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided by @MattKing, you can use this formula to remove the 0 row

```
=QUERY(Dump!A2:F,"SELECT A,F, COUNT(C) where A<>'' GROUP BY A,F label count(C) ''")
```

Or you can exclude the header using 0 value as stated by @doubleunary

```
=query(Dump!A1:F, "select A, F, count(C) group by A, F label count(C) '' ", 0)
```